# How do I format column headers with python 2.7's csv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm building a script to transfer data from one csv file to another csv file.  The base functionality works, but I need to programmatically build the headers for the file.

Specifically, I need one column header denoting a month value.  This header needs to span 10 columns.  The next line I need to have column headers that span two lines denoting data that occurred in that month.

This needs to be done programmatically because - ideally - I could just run the script any time I get new data.

For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbqgj.jpg

Is this possible inside of python?  Is this just something that would be basically impossible?

Comment: Can you post text from two sample files.  The starting and ending file.  Just a header and a line or two is great!

Comment: It sounds like you want to merge cells, which I don't think is compatible with CSV files at all.

Comment: @Adam I added an example of what I'm looking for.  I'm not adding in any data from anything because you don't need that.  I know how to write the hard data, I don't know how to *format* headers so they span multiple columns.  The other information you're asking for is completely irrelevant to my question.

Comment: That's not possible using standard CSV. You can use the [`xlsxwriter`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) module to write an Excel file formatted like that, tho.

Comment: Thanks guys for the info - did not know that CSV didn't support that!  I will be sure to use the xlsxwriter instead as per @zwer 's suggestion :)